# Why does standalone master schedule drivers on a worker?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

The `schedule()` in `Master.scala` shows the first schedule task is scheduling drivers on Workers. As Master will start only standalone mode, drivers will run on client out of Spark cluster.

Why does the master need schedule a Worker to run Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to [private def schedule(): Unit](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/master/Master.scala#L703), that method schedules the drivers of Spark applications that were `spark-submit` using `--deploy-mode cluster`.

From [Launching Applications with spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) (that is linked from [Cluster Mode Overview](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html)):

> **--deploy-mode** Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (`cluster`) or locally as an external client (`client`) (default: `client`)

In `cluster` deploy mode, the driver runs on a worker in a cluster (and is irrespective of the cluster manager, Spark Standalone, Hadoop YARN or Apache Mesos). As are Spark executors.